# Some columns from a dataframe in Jupyter Notebook are rendered as HTML in GitHub. How to render it not in HTML?

Tags: python, sql-server, dataframe, github, jupyter-notebook

Within SQL query I converted numbers that showcase Revenue to the currency format (while working in Jupyter Notebook) and it is rendering well there:

```
top_ten_df = pd.read_sql("WITH revenue_by_product AS "
                     "(SELECT p.Name AS ProductName, pm.Name AS Model, "
                     "FORMAT(SUM(pod.LineTotal), 'C2','en-US') AS Revenue "
                     "FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod "
                     "INNER JOIN Production.Product p "
                     "ON pod.ProductID = p.ProductID "
                     "INNER JOIN Production.ProductModel pm "
                     "ON pm.ProductModelID = p.ProductModelID "
                     "GROUP BY p.Name, pm.Name "
                     "ORDER BY SUM(pod.LineTotal) DESC "
                     "OFFSET 0 ROWS "
                     "FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY) "
                     "SELECT ProductName, Model, Revenue "
                     "FROM revenue_by_product "
                     "ORDER BY Revenue DESC;", conn)

display(top_ten_df)
```

Here is how it looks in a dataframe: [image: screenshot]

However, when I pushed this Notebook to the GitHub repository, the currency depicts in a weird format there:
[image: screenshot]

The code that was pushed to GitHub is the same, but the column with currency in the dataframe looks wrong.

I've already tried transforming the data into currency via dataframe (rather than SQL query)

```
def format(x):
   return "${:,.2f}".format(x)
top_ten_df['Revenue'] = top_ten_df['Revenue'].apply(format)

display(top_ten_df)
```

but it still shows HTML in GitHub.

Is there a way to upload a dataframe generated from SQL query to GitHub showcasing the currency in the right format?

Comment: Please don't use imaged for code, data or errors. Use formatted text.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I've adjusted the post